# Align the items to top of the card

Tags: css

I want the both sub-cards in cluster -1 and 2 align in the top, where as they are aligning in the bottom. Do check the css and screenshot. Where .cards refer to clusters and sub-cards-rec and sub-cards-ana refers to the sub-cards present inside the each cluster.
Please look into this problem why the cards are not aligned from the top but are aligned in the bottom.

```
<CardGroup>
      <Card className="cards">
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Cluster-1</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text> </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-ana">
          <Card.Header>Analysis Unit - 1</Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
            <div className="response">
              <h6>Response status: {state.msgStatus} {state.strStatusText}</h6>
              {/* <h6> Output: {JSON.stringify(state.data)}</h6> */}
            </div>
            <Card.Text>
            <h6><Badge pill bg="warning" >System usage:{}</Badge></h6>
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card><br/>
        <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-rec">
          <Card.Header>Recording Unit - 1</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
              <h6><Badge style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgreen" }} onClick={onGetClusters}>Cluster Info</Badge></h6>
              <h6><Badge pill bg="primary">Cumulative Data Rate:{'140KBps'}</Badge></h6>
              
              {/* <h6 onClick={toggle}><Badge pill bg="primary" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{}</Badge></h6> */}

              {css ? (<h6 onClick={toggle2}><Badge pill bg="success" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{'Online'}</Badge></h6>)
              :(<h6 onClick={toggle2}><Badge pill bg="danger" >Cumulative Sensor Status:{'Offline'}</Badge></h6>)
              }
              </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card><br/>
      </Card><br/>

      <Card className="cards">
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Cluster-2</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text></Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-ana">
          <Card.Header>Analysis Unit - 1</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              <h6><Badge pill bg="warning" >System usage:{}</Badge></h6>
            </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card><br />
        <Card border="secondary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className ="sub-cards-ana">
          <Card.Header>Analysis Unit - 2</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>[ID]</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
              <h6><Badge pill bg="warning" >System usage:{}</Badge></h6>    
            </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card><br />
      </Card>
    </CardGroup>
```

```css
.cards{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    box-sizing: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: fit-content;
    padding-right:40px;
}

.cards .sub-cards-rec{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(161, 160, 233);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cards .sub-cards-ana{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(163, 229, 157);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the corresponding HTML code?

Comment: Please update the question with relavent HTML code.

Comment: Added the cards and sub-cards code

Answer (score 0):

assuming .cards is the container divs that both columns of cards are in then use this.

```
  .cards{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 5px;
        box-sizing: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        max-width: fit-content;
        padding-right:40px;
    }
```

Comment: But this isnt working.